# How can I get latest list of records per matter id?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view that populates a form in our Extranet. We only want to see the latest data for each group of Matter Numbers.

In the image below we don't want to see any event dates to the right of where it's RED because they are old events. We do want to keep the data that is to the left.

The rows I have highlighted in the tables are the rows that should appear in the Extranet form.

[image]

Each line is a different Matter Number.

This is the view that was created to pull the data.

I can't figure out how to only show the latest events.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT e.eventsno        AS DocketID, 
 M1.mattercode, 
 M1.clientid, 
 M1.matterid,
 M1.AreaofLaw,
 DocketCode, 
 e.eventdate         AS StartDate, 
 e.enddate,
 et.eventdesc, 
 Cast(e.notes AS VARCHAR(4096)) AS Summary 
FROM   dbo.events AS e 
 INNER JOIN dbo.eventmatters AS em 
         ON em.events = e.events 
 INNER JOIN dbo.matters AS m 
         ON m.matters = em.matters 
 INNER JOIN dbo.eventtypes AS et 
         ON et.eventtypes = e.eventtypes 
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.vu_lp2_matters AS M1 
               ON M1.mattercode = m.matterid 
 WHERE   e.eventkind = 'D' 
 AND   e.eventtypes IN (SELECT eventtypes 
                        FROM   dbo.events 
                        WHERE  ( et.eventdesc <> 'Accounts Receivable' 
                                  OR et.eventdesc NOT LIKE 'Reminder%' ) 
     ) 
 AND ( e.eventdate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 102))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help.  I ended up using a CTE to get the data to display properly.  Below is the completed script.

```
 With cte As 
 (Select e.EventsNo, 
    m1.MatterCode,
    m1.ClientID,
    m1.MatterID,
    m1.AreaOfLaw,
    e.EventTypes    AS DocketCode, 
    e.EventDate,
    e.EndDate, 
    et.DocketDesc ,
    Cast(e.notes AS VARCHAR(4096)) Summary ,
    Row_Number() Over(Partition By MatterCode Order By EventDate Desc) AS rnLastOverAll,
    Row_Number() Over(Partition By MatterCode, DocketDesc Order By EventDate Desc) As rnLastByDocDesc
 FROM   dbo.events e 
 INNER JOIN dbo.eventmatters em ON em.events = e.events
 INNER JOIN dbo.matters m ON m.matters = em.matters 
 INNER JOIN dbo.vu_LP2_DocketCodes et ON et.DocketCode = e.eventtypes 
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.vu_lp2_matters M1 ON M1.mattercode = m.matterid 
 WHERE e.eventkind = 'D'
 )

 Select c2.EventsNo 'DocketID',c2.MatterCode,c2.ClientID,c2.MatterID, c2.AreaOfLaw,
 c2.DocketCode, c2.EventDate 'StartDate', c2.EndDate, c2.DocketDesc, c2.Summary
 From cte c1
 Inner Join cte c2 On c1.MatterCode = c2.MatterCode And c2.rnLastByDocDesc = 1  
 And (
  (c1.DocketDesc = 'Demand' And c2.DocketDesc In ('Demand'))
  Or (c1.DocketDesc = 'Complaint' And c2.DocketDesc In ('Demand', 'Complaint'))
  Or (c1.DocketDesc = 'Pre-Trial' And c2.DocketDesc In ('Demand', 'Complaint', 'Pre-Trial'))
  Or (c1.DocketDesc = 'Post Judgment' And c2.DocketDesc In ('Demand', 'Complaint', 'Pre-Trial', 'Post Judgment'))
  Or (c1.DocketDesc = 'Stop Collections' And c2.DocketDesc In ('Demand', 'Complaint', 'Pre-Trial', 'Post Judgment', 'Stop Collections'))
) Where c1.rnLastOverAll = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER/RANK` to get first value for each group:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY M1.mattercode ORDER BY e.eventdate DESC) AS rn
    -- your complex query
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER function  to your query  , order the partition by event date descending and filter records having row_number =1 :

```
SELECT * from (
  SELECT e.eventsno        AS DocketID, 
     M1.mattercode, 
     M1.clientid, 
     M1.matterid,
     M1.AreaofLaw,
     DocketCode, 
     e.eventdate         AS StartDate, 
     e.enddate,
     et.eventdesc, 
     Cast(e.notes AS VARCHAR(4096)) AS Summary ,
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY M1.mattercode order by e.eventdate desc) as row_no
    FROM   dbo.events AS e 
     INNER JOIN dbo.eventmatters AS em 
             ON em.events = e.events 
     INNER JOIN dbo.matters AS m 
             ON m.matters = em.matters 
     INNER JOIN dbo.eventtypes AS et 
             ON et.eventtypes = e.eventtypes 
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.vu_lp2_matters AS M1 
                   ON M1.mattercode = m.matterid 
     WHERE   e.eventkind = 'D' 
     AND   e.eventtypes IN (SELECT eventtypes 
                            FROM   dbo.events 
                            WHERE  ( et.eventdesc <> 'Accounts Receivable' 
                                      OR et.eventdesc NOT LIKE 'Reminder%' ) 
         ) 
     AND ( e.eventdate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 102))
) TMP where row_no=1
```

Comment: How this answer is different for answer below (CTE -> subquery is basically the same)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is only bringing back the top row.  I have edited the original question to clarify what is required.

Comment: from your question, you need latest event per group of Matter Numbers. Is mattercode is group of Matter Numbers?

Comment: I didn't explain it properly which is why I edited the original post.  Here are the rules.  If the latest event is 'Demand' then only show the date for 'Demand'. If the latest event is 'Complaint' then show the latest dates for  'Demand' AND 'Complaint'. If the latest event is 'Pre-Trial' then show the latest dates for 'Demand', 'Complaint', and 'Pre-Trial'...etc  I hope this helps.